# Express JSON parse by JSON and by text

Tags: express

I currently have 2 consumers of the same, Express JS, API.
When I run my API locally I have to specify either:

```
app.use(express.text);
```

or:

```
app.use(express.json);
```

Depending on what content-type is being sent to the API.
Is there a way I can handle both content-types or contextually handle the contents of the request as currently I can only use one or the other and not both at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify both:

```js
app.use(express.text(), express.json());
```

(don't forget the parentheses).

The `text()` middleware parses the incoming request only if `Content-Type: text/plain`, whereas `json()` parses only `Content-Type: application/json`. This is important, because every incoming request can be parsed only *once*. After `req.body` has been filled by the `text()` middleware, say, the entire request payload has been consumed, and subsequent middlewares cannot consume it again.

Comment: Absolutely fantastic, thank you very much.